# How to convert minutes to find how many number of years are in those minutes?

Tags: java, algorithm

Program that prompts the user to enter the minutes(e.g., 1 billion), and display the number of years and days for the minutes.

Comment: Due to leap years, the number of years/days would depend not only on the number of minutes but also on the start date. Also, you'll have to show what you already tried.

Comment: For one billion minutes, it's ~1901 years.

Comment: What's the problem you're having? You can't figure out how many minutes there are in a day and how many days there are in a year? Please be more specific.

Comment: Is just an assignment. I didn't had any code written out. I couldn't find the formula to convert any minute given to number of years.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

1. **Show us the code you tried.**
2. If you're still stuck, you can simply divide the number of minutes by appropriate number to get years and days. On an average, you can assume the days per year to be [365.2425](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Year) if the number of minutes is high enough (atleast in the range of millions (why?))

   ```
   // store the value in the field minutes.
   double minutes;

   double years = minutes/(60*24*365.2425);

   /* 
   This will ignore the part after the decimal. 
   The part after the decimal is not a complete year, 
   so it'll be used to calculate the number of days. 
   */
   int absoluteYears = (int)years; 

   double days = (years - absoluteYears)*365.2425;
   ```

You can round-off the number of days by casting `days` to `int` to report the final answer in integral form.